# Dialog flow default fall back

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Hello So I am creating a chat bot with two language, A is supported and B is not supported(I used A and B so it will be easier to read) and the issues is I want to have default fall back for both but when I type random word for B it always call the default fallback of A. I also tried create a normal intent and name it fallback for B and add some phrase and it work but when I type random word for A it call the fallback of B. Is there any work around for the issues?
Would appreciate any answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there won't be a good work around for this as Dialogflow works with one NLP model per language. By trying to fit two languages into one model, you are creating a difficult scenario. The fallback intents are meant as a safety net in case of unrecognized input for the language of the NLP model, your second languages will always end up in the fallback intent as it is unrecognized input for the first language.

Yes you could create a custom fallback intent by entering words manually, but this isn't a valid solution since you cant fit every word of a language into an intent. So you will end up with certain words of the second language going into the custom fallback and some not.

In general it isn't recommended to fit two languages in a NLP model, so my recommendation would be to drop the unsupported language and wait for it to become supported, this will give you the best bot and experience.

If you would really need the second language, one thing you could try is add another supported language that you won't be using and train that on words of your unsupported language. Note: This NLP model will be very restricted in its features as it will only respond to the words you trained it to, build in entities won't work as your language is still unsupported, but it allows you to do some work with an unsupported language, but again, it will be very limited.

Comment: Hello, Sorry to bother but I have another question. What if I separate the two language into two different agent but one of them is still unsupported. Is there a method that when the user choose the language in the chat it call one of the agent?So in this case it will be easy to use the fallback. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that is possible and if it is possible, you will still run into the issue of having a limited experience because the language is still unsupported. Changing the agent gives you the same result as adding another language in the same agent.

Comment: Oh okay understood. Thank you so much .

Comment: Hello one last question so if I added another additional language in the agent and copy all the unsupported language intent into that additional language, Can the user pick the language like in facebook chat and is there an api that will call that additional language in my agent? Thank you.

Comment: That isn't something that I would know

Comment: Thank you so much.